# AWS lambda Nodejs function can't find the 'whereis' command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The basic question is, is it possible to give a AWS Lambda function the 'whereis' command?

For a little more context, I'm converting a standard Node JS project into a project that uses AWS Lambda (still Node JS) as a backend and a S3 bucket for the frontend (not my decision).

So far it hasn't been too problematic.  But I've run into an error when trying to use the font-list library's getFonts() method.  It generates the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: whereis fc-list
/bin/sh: whereis: command not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12) {
  code: 127,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'whereis fc-list',
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '/bin/sh: whereis: command not found\n'
```

If you really need the code I'm running, it is:

```
static async get(body, res) {
    await fontList.getFonts().then(fonts => {
        res['body']['fonts'] = fonts;
    }).catch(err => {

        res['status'] = 400;
        res['body'] = {'error': err};
    });
};
```

Is there a fix for this or will I have to look into some other way of getting a consistent list of available fonts?

Comment: Why serve fonts dynamically from a webserver? Couldn't you serve them statically from S3 or a CDN?

Comment: Didn't realize that there existed CDN's for Fonts.  I will have to see if it's possible to get lists of their available fonts and get back to you on if that will work. As far as S3, it sounds like I would have to manually create such a bucket, and add fonts to it.  That would be too much work for just wanting a list of selectable fonts.

Comment: You already have an S3 bucket for the front-end, no? Aren't the fonts something that the front-end uses? Why is the back-end involved in listing fonts?

Comment: AWS Lambdas are meant to be fast, that is why they are using Firecracker VMs and Microkernels. I bet that they are stripping the underlying OS of all the "unnecessary" binaries that one would typically not need, including binaries like `whereis`. But I also agree with the others. Fonts come from S3/CDN. So this part of the code probably needs to be refactored.

Comment: @jarmod It isn't so much the creation of the bucket, but the adding fonts to it one by one.  I don't have the time to do such a task.  I will just go with the CDN idea and refactor.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out to me, that CDN's exists for fonts (Google's likely being the one I use). I will be refactoring the code to pull from their list of Fonts instead of using font-list anymore.